# Prolog remove brackets from string

Tags: string, prolog, brackets

How to remove brackets from string in Prolog.
I have only {} brackets, and there might be nested brackets.

for example if I have a string

> a{1+{2}+3}b{4}c

then the answer will be string

> abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy with **[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** notation.

The following assumes that you have the setting:

> `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`

in your initialization file, to work more conveniently with **characters**.

For example:

```
no_braces([])     --> [].
no_braces([C|Cs]) --> [C], { dif(C, '{') }, no_braces(Cs).
no_braces(Cs)     --> ['{'], no_braces(_), ['}'], no_braces(Cs).
```

Sample queries and answers:

```
?- phrase(no_braces(Ls), "abc").
Ls = [a, b, c] ;
false.

?- phrase(no_braces(Ls), "a{b}c").
Ls = [a, c] ;
false.
```

We can also post very general queries and *still* obtain answers:

```
?- length(Ls0, _), phrase(no_braces(Ls), Ls0).
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_2308],
dif(_2308, '{') ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_2474, _2480],
dif(_2474, '{'),
dif(_2480, '{') ;
Ls0 = ['{', '}'],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_2640, _2646, _2652],
dif(_2640, '{'),
dif(_2646, '{'),
dif(_2652, '{') .
```

At last, your example:

```
?- phrase(no_braces(Ls), "a{1+{2}+3}b{4}c").
Ls = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```